# What is Eol in text file and normal file?

Tags: c++

Now I am quite confused about the end of line character I am working with c++ and I know that text files have a end of line marker which sets the limit for reading a line which a single shifing operator(>>).Data is read continously untill eol character does not apprears and while opening a file in text mode carriage return(CR) is converted into CRLF which is eol marker so if i add white spaces in my text then would it act as eol maker cause it does.

Now i created a normal file i.e. a file without .txt 
eg

```
 ifstream("test"); // No .txt
```

Now what is eol marker in this case

Comment: "cause it does" No it doesn't.  Why do you think it does?

Answer (score 3):

The ".txt" at the end of the filename is just a convention. It's just *part of the filename*.

It does not signify any magical property of the file, and it certainly doesn't change how the file is handled by your operating system kernel or file system driver.

So, in short, what difference is there? **None.**

---

> I know that text files have a end of line marker which sets the limit for reading a line which a single shifing operator(>>)

That is incorrect.

> Data is read continously untill eol character does not apprears

Also incorrect. Some operating systems (e.g. Windows IIRC) inject an EOF (not EOL!) character into the stream to signify to calling applications that there is no more data to read. Other operating systems don't even do that. But in neither case is there an actual EOF character at the end of the actual file.

> while opening a file in text mode carriage return(CR) is converted into CRLF which is eol marker

That conversion may or may not happen and, either way, EOL is not EOF.

> if i add white spaces in my text then would it act as eol maker cause it does.

That's a negative, star command.

I'm not sure where you're getting all this stuff from, but you've been heavily mistaught. I suggest a good, peer-reviewed, well-recommended book from Amazon about how computer operating systems work.

Comment: if i enter "Hello man how are you" then what will be enter in the file?? Because when i read it in c++ appears "Hellomanhowareyou" but you said that it will be read continously untill eol does not appear

Comment: and you said that there are no differences is it so??

Comment: @Harshul your misunderstandings and wrong assumptions of the basics of file IO is preventing you to understand the explanation.  My advice: unlearn anything you think you know about file IO and start from scratch. A good book, even a good online tutorial, or just start doing simple readings/writings from a simple file to get accustomed to it.

Answer (score 0):

When reading *strings* in C++ using the extraction operator >>, the default is to skip spaces.

If you want the entire line verbatim, use `std::getline`.

A typical input loop is:

```
int main(void)
{
  std::string text_from_file;
  std::ifstream input_file("My_data.txt");
  if (!input_file)
  {
    cerr << "Error opening My_data.txt for reading.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  while (input_file >> text_from_file)
  {
    // Process the variable text_from_file.
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of old and mainframe operating systems required a record structure of all data files which, for text files, originated with a Hollerith (punch) card of 80 columns and was faithfully preserved through disk file records, magnetic tapes, output punch card decks, and line printer lines.  No line ending was used because the record structure required that every record have 80 columns (and were typically filled with spaces).  In later years (1960s+), having variable length records with an 80 column maximum became popular.  Today, even OpenVMS still requires the file creator to specify a file format (sequential, indexed, or "stream") and record size (fixed, variable) where the maximum record size must be specified in advance.

In the modern era of computing (which effectively began with Unix) it is widely considered a bad idea to force a structure on data files.  Any programmer is free to do that to themselves and there are plenty of record-oriented data formats like compiler/linker object files (.obj, .so, .o, .lib, .exe, etc.), and most media formats (.gif, .tiff, .flv, .mov, mp3, etc.)

For communicating text lines, the paradigm is to target a terminal or printer and for that, line endings should be indicated.  Most operating systems environments (except MSDOS and Windows) use the `\n` character which is encoded in ASCII as a linefeed (ASCII 10) code.  MSDOS and ilk use '\r\n' which are encoded as carriage return then linefeed (ASCII 13, 10).  There are advantages and disadvantages to both schemes.  But text files may also contain other controls, most commonly the [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) which control devices in specific ways:

- clear the screen, either in part or all of it
- eject a printer page, skip some lines, reverse feed, and other little-used features
- establish a scrolling region
- change the text color
- selecting a font, text weight, page size, etc.

For these operations, line endings are not a concern.

Also, data files encoded in ASCII such as JSON and XML (especially HTML with embedded Javascript), might not have *any* line endings, especially when the data is obfuscated or compressed.

---

To answer your questions:

> I am quite confused about the end of line character I am working with c++ and I know that text files have a end of line marker

Maybe.  Maybe not.  From a C or C++ program's viewpoint, writing `\n` indicates to the runtime environment the end of a line.  What the system does with that varies by runtime operating environment.  For Unix and Linux, no translation occurs (though writing to a terminal-like device converts to `\r\n`).  In MSDOS, '\n' is translated to `\r\n`.  In OpenVMS, '\n' is removed and that record's size is set.  Reading does the inverse translation.

> which sets the limit for reading a line which a single shifing operator(>>).

There is no such limit:  A program can choose to read data byte-by-byte if it wants as well as ignore the line boundaries.

The "shifting operators" are overloaded for filestreams to input or output data but are not related to [bit twiddling shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift).  These operators were chosen for visual approximation of input/output and due to their low operator precedence.

> Data is read continously untill eol character does not apprears

This bit is confusing:  I think you meant *until eol character appears*, which is indeed how the line-oriented functions [`gets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) and [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) work.

> and while opening a file in text mode carriage return(CR) is converted into CRLF which is eol marker so if i add white spaces in my text then would it act as eol maker cause it does.

Opening the file does not convert anything, but reading from a file might.  However, no environment (that I know of) converts input to CR LF.  MSDOS converts CR LF on input to `\n`.

Adding spaces has no effect on end of lines, end of file, or anything.  Spaces are just data.  However, the C++ streaming operations reading/writing numbers and some other datatypes use whitespace (a sequence of spaces, horizontal tabs, vertical tabs, form feed, and maybe some others) as a delimiter.  This convenience feature may cause some confusion.

> Now i created a normal file i.e. a file without .txt eg
>
> ifstream("test"); \No .txt
>
> Now what is eol marker in this case

The filename does *not* determine the file type.  In fact, `file.txt` may not be a text file at all.  Using a particular file extension is convenient for humans to communicate a file's purpose, but it is not obligatory.

Comment: Ow!  The modern computer era began with Unix??  Think it began at least in the 60s with the PDP-8 which was well before Unix ...

Comment: @RichardHammond:  I don't consider computers of the 1960s, especially if they used OS-enforced record structure, *modern computer systems*.  The PDP-8 was, at best, a bridge between iron dinosaurs of the time to mini-computers of the 1970s.  A fully-decked-out PDP-8 had 4K 12-bit words, or about 5 K bytes of memory.  It is hard to call that a modern architecture.  A minimal [Arduino Uno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino_Uno) has 32 K of program storage and 2 K of RAM.

Comment: So you're 1 against the thousands (tens of thousands?) of people who sold/programmed/used/operated IBM 360s/370s and ICL 1900 systems in the '60s which were rightly considered to be 'modern' (and non-Unix!) computer systems.  There are millions of people who might consider a machine which stored code and data in its memory 'modern'. Whatever - my point is that the modern era of computing DIDN'T begin with Unix - it at least began with Turing and Kilburn (my old prof) in 1948 when they developed the first stored-program computer.  Sorry, old bean, you're opinion is your own but its wrong ...

Comment: @RichardHammond:   Ask yourself what [*modern*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/modern?s=t) means (one meaning is *not obsolete*).  Then look at anything which progresses:  lighting technology, clothing, vehicles, etc.  Do you consider a carbide lamp to be modern?  That versus a white LED light is arguably comparable advancement in usefulness and functionality as a 1948 computer versus a recent 2.5+ GHz PC.

Comment: You're widening the discussion because you're on the back foot here. I would suggest - and millions more might agree with me - that the modern era of lighting began with Edison, yes? no? Our discussion, though, isn't about one particular word and its meaning. The modern era of computing (your words) DIDN'T begin with Unix!  Stop wriggling Wally!